# How to make a blur background with custom shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, blur

I want to achieve the below widget :

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? What are you struggling with? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service and as it stands your question is very broad

Comment: @jraufeisen Yes I know but I have a challenge with this. I don't know how to achieve this UI in Flutter. I tried the BackDropFilter widget but did not success in creating this.